# Excluding (certain) messages from selected plugins in the VSCode "Problems" tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

How one can exclude certain plugins and messages they generate from the "Problems" tab in VSCode in an *elegant* way (e.g. through `.code-workspace` JSON or global settings for specific filetypes, like `.tex`)?

I'd like to keep these plugins on, I'd just like to declutter the Problems tab from certain messages in a reusable way.

Namely, I'd like to clean it from all Grammarly plugin issues and certain LaTeX plugin messages (such as the infamous `overfull \hbox`).

[image: Grammarly issues in the Problems tab]

Comment: so you don't want a solution that uses the builtin filter input? because you can write exclusion patterns in that filter input. what you mean by "elegant" is really unclear.